# Hibernate not generating child id on cascade all save

Tags: java, hibernate

Parent Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "****")
@Audited
public class Ship
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String              id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "associatedShip", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<ShipLoadlineInformation>   loadlineInformation = new ArrayList<ShipLoadlineInformation>(0);

    .. with other fields constructors, getters and setters.
}
```

Child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "*********")
@Audited
public class ShipLoadlineInformation
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String      id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ASSOCIATED_SHIP")
    private Ship        associatedShip;

    .. with other fields, constructors, getter and setters
}
```

I am saving it in my DAO as follows:

```
    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(ship);
```

When i try to save the object ship its giving me following error:

> org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session :
>   [com.tms.model.transportMode.ShipLoadlineInformation#]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:618)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:301)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:244)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:109)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:235)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]

When  debugging it, found out that the id for the parent class is getting generated. But the id for child class is not being generated.

I think this is the cause. Correct me if i am wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can occur when detached `ShipLoadlineInformation` instances are contained in the `Ship.loadlineInformation` collection. This way `save` action is cascaded to them when you save `ship`.

The easiest way to get around it is to merge the ship (thus cascading `merge` operation to `loadlineInformation` as well).

So, in your DAO replace:

```
this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(ship)
```

with:

```
ship = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(ship)
```